# How can i increase the height of textview in upper side instead of regular bottom side?

Tags: ios, swift

I want to increase height of textview according content of textview increase. i tried different way but i did't get solution to increase height in up direction. [Attached image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tbBHn.png)

Comment: please view this link https://github.com/rcmcastro/whatsapp-ios

Comment: according to your image, you should add bottom constraint to fix the textView vertically downward. Then when you increase the size it will appear to increase height in upward direction

Answer (score 3):

Change frame of UITextView in textViewDidChange delegate method,

```
func textViewDidChange(_ textView: UITextView) {
    let fixedWidth = textView.frame.size.width
    textView.sizeThatFits(CGSize(width: fixedWidth, height: CGFloat.greatestFiniteMagnitude))
    let newSize = textView.sizeThatFits(CGSize(width: fixedWidth, height: CGFloat.greatestFiniteMagnitude))
    var textViewFrame = textView.frame
    textViewFrame = CGRect.init(x: textViewFrame.origin.x, y: textViewFrame.origin.y+textViewFrame.height-newSize.height, width: max(newSize.width, fixedWidth), height: newSize.height)
    textView.frame = textViewFrame
}
```

It will increase size of UITextView from bottom.

Answer (score 0):

After setting the text, so in the viewWillLayoutSubView()

```
let contentSize = textView.sizeThatFits(textView.bounds.size)
```

After that you will be able to use the contentSize Height:

```
height: contentSize.height
```

Comment: I did't asked how to set height. I asked how to increase height from bottom.